# Bug when saving an edit: I made my post disappear

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

When saving an edit, I am asked if I want to abandon the edit:

[image]

Then, if I choose cancel, the post disappears:

[image]

It works on questions too:

[image]

This is on iOS Safari.

Meta.se report here: [Editing a post leads to weird behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375054/editing-a-post-leads-to-a-weird-behavior)

Comment: I repro. The post disappears even before the dialog box opens.

Comment: Exact same thing just happened to me (including the last screenshot) when editing an answer. W10 Chrome

Comment: meta.SE post reporting same behavior: [Editing a post leads to a weird behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375054/311001)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: thanks a lot to everybody for notifying us about this issue. We have been able to reproduce and fix the issue. Please do let us know (in a comment to this answer) if you're still encountering any issues with this.

Comment: Thank you! All clear.